# Django ORM m2m limit to 1

Tags: django, django-orm

```python
# models.py
class Gallery(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, null=True, blank=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()


# views.py
class GalleryIndex(ListView):
    model = Gallery
```

I need to get thumbnail for every gallery, which is it's very first/last/whatever image.
How can I LIMIT image by 1 for any gallery as a custom attribute (to not override `Gallery.images`) without calling second SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've read docs better. Standard QuerySet API can't handle such cases efficiently (`annotate()` generates `GROUP BY` clause for each of parent fields which is slow) so I come with `extra()` method and raw subquery.

```python
class GalleryIndex(ListView):
    queryset = Gallery.objects.extra(select={'thumb':
        """
        SELECT "image"
        FROM "app_image", "app_gallery_images"
        WHERE (
            "app_gallery"."id" = "app_gallery_images"."gallery_id"
            AND "app_gallery_images"."image_id" = "app_image"."id"
        )
        AND "app_image"."image" IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 1
        """
    })
```

This queryset do exactly what I wanted, since SorlImageField (and ImageField) needs only filename to represent thumbnail in templates.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many acts as a descriptor for a normal queryset, so you can do `my_gallery.images.all()[0]` to limit the query to 1.

Comment: That's works only per gallery, but not for all of them… Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand correctly what you want to do, but doesn't below code work for you?

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_thumb(self):
        return self.images.all()[0]
```

Or maybe other concept:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thumbnail = self.images.all()[0].image
```

(some exception catching here needed though)

Comment: I want to select either galleries and their first image as their custom attribute within single SQL query. 
First example still generate one + N queries (where N is number of galleries).
Second example can't exists in my case because of custom logic for thumbnails selection…

Comment: It's not even selection, rather than populating `Image` and `Gallery` models are totally independent and separated (that's why `images` field is nullable).
I've reduced SQL queries to two by providing `queryset = Gallery.objects.prefetch_related('images').all()` to view class… But still, it's 2 queries, not one.

Comment: That still doesn't explain too much, but I would the way I described. Eventually change `Gallery.thumbnail` to `thumbnail_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)`  and the rest should be a matter of updating data - signals or save() methods

Comment: Or maybe caching is the way to go?